# Given 'Windows Firewall with Advanced Security', why is there a 'Windows Firewall'?

Tags: windows-firewall

Windows Server 2008: why on earth is Microsoft giving us two firewalls within the OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that it's not a separate firewall from Windows Firewall, it's a more advanced management console for Windows Firewall.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=DF192E1B-A92A-4075-9F69-C12B7C54B52B&displaylang=en

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748991(WS.10).aspx

Comment: Thankx Joe...I can see how those links lead to that conclusion - same firewall, different UI. However...I can turn off the old firewall - windows tells me I running in a non-recommended state, then open windows firewall with advanced security - it insists it's running with all profiles active. any thoughts? thx

Comment: Opps...i wasn't looking close enough - the 'Private' profile _was off. Making more sense now. sry 'n thankx again.

Comment: Glad to help...